Incomplete Data from Big Query -> Google Ads Data Transfer
I am having a problem getting complete data for an entire time range using the Google Ads Data Transfer with Big Query. I am new to this so I would appreciate any guidance.
Today is 10/18/2024 and I set the start date and run time of my data transfer to 9/1/2024 to capture this month and the previous month's data.
The transfer was successful according to my run history and there was some Google Ads data put into my BQ dataset, but it only showed yesterday's data. It did not give me complete data from 9/1/2024 - 10/18/2024.
In troubleshooting, I scheduled a backfill over the time range of 9/1/2024 - 10/18/2024, but it only gave me data for 9/20/2024 - 10/18/2024. It says it ran successfully and there are no errors anywhere within BigQuery, yet I still have less data when compared to the actual platform.
I know for certain that my Google Ads campaigns have data between 9/1 and 9/20 so this is definitely incomplete data.
Did I set things up wrong? Is there a limit being imposed on my account? Is my SQL Query to grab the data wrong?
SELECT
  cs._DATA_DATE as date,
  cl.campaign_name,
  SUM(metrics_cost_micros) / 1000000 as cost,
  SUM(metrics_impressions) as impressions,
  SUM(metrics_clicks) as clicks,
FROM
  `client.google_ads.ads_CampaignBasicStats_123456789` cs
JOIN
  `client.google_ads.ads_CampaignLabel_123456789` cl
ON
  cs.campaign_id = cl.campaign_id
GROUP BY 
 1,2
ORDER BY 
  cs._DATA_DATE asc

